# redirect output to compressed format (C)

Tags: c, printf, compression

Is it possible to use `fprintf` in such a way that write data to a compressed file?
For example:

```
fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
```

will write to a plain text file. So the file size grows very large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zlib` to write data to a compressed stream.

```
gzFile fp;
fp = gzopen(NAME, "wb");
gzprintf(fp, "Hello, %s!\n", "world");
gzclose(fp);
```

Compile it like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o zprog zprog.c -lz
```

Use `zcat` to print the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3):

The minimally-invasive solution if you're on a system that has pipes would be to open a pipe to an external `gzip` process. That way you can use all the normal stdio output functions without having to replace everything with zlib calls.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you could use the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library (and link it as `-lz`) and use its [compressed streams](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Stream)